# Graphing multiple variables in R

Tags: r, graph

I am currently attempting to graph multiple columns in a matrix in R. So far, I have figured things out, but here is my problem- when I submit a matrix with 5 columns, I only get a graph with 4 lines. I've noticed that the missing line is always the line closest to the x-axis. I've been working on this for several hours now, and I have tried several different things. Any advice or help on how to get R to produce that 5th line (with a corresponding color filling the space between the x-axis and the line) would be greatly appreciated.

```
    gender=cbind(matrix(malepop),matrix(femalepop))
    plotmat(year,gender) 
    #a sample set
    biggen=cbind(malepop,femalepop,malepop,femalepop)
    #start of the function
    plotmat2=function(years,m,colors){
      n=m/1000000
      #create a plot with the base line
      plot(years,n[,1],type='l',ylim=c(0,10))
      ##create a for loop to generate all other lines and fill in the spaces
      for (i in ncol(n):2) {
        newpop=matrix(rowSums(n[,1:i]))
        lines(year,newpop)
        cord.xmat=c(min(years),years,max(years))
        cord.ymat=c(-1,newpop[,1],-1)
        polygon(cord.xmat,cord.ymat,col=clrs[i])
        next
        cord.xmat=c(min(years),years,max(years))
        cord.ymat1=c(-1,n[,1]/1000000,-1)
        polygon(cord.xmat,cord.ymat,col="purple")
      }
     }
    #sample color set
    clrs=c("red","blue","yellow","pink","purple", "cyan", "hotpink")
    #run the function
    plotmat2(year,biggen,clrs)
```

[image: This is what I'm getting currently (the blue space should have another line somewhere in the midst of it which has the color red filling between that line and the x-axis]

Thanks for any and all help you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you are unintentionally covering up your first line with the other colored sections, and that you may be skipping the creation of the polygon for n[,1].

From the way you tried to graph the columns in descending order, I am assuming you know that your columns are in ascending size order (the section that is pink in your example plot would be the final column in the matrix "biggen").  In case I am wrong about this, it might be a good idea to change your polygon shading using the density argument, which may help you see if you are covering up other sections by accident.

```
## plotmat2 function
plotmat2=function(years,m,colors){
      n=m/1000000

      #create a blank plot based on the baseline
      plot(years,n[,1],type='n',ylim=c(0,10))

      ##create a for loop to generate all other lines and fill in the spaces
      for (i in ncol(n):1) {
        newpop=matrix(rowSums(n[,1:i]))
        lines(year,newpop)
        cord.xmat=c(min(years),years,max(years))
        cord.ymat=c(-1,newpop[,1],-1)
        polygon(cord.xmat,cord.ymat,col=colors[i], density=10)
      }
 }
```

P.S. If this doesn't help fix the problem, it might help if you provided a portion of your dataset. I am still learning about R and about StackOverflow, but that seems to be sensible advice that is given on a lot of the threads I have read on here.  Good luck!